# jQuery .html() help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#ipad").submit(function() {
    $.post("ipadcheck.php", $("#ipad").serialize(),
    function(data) 
    {
        if(data.error == 'TRUE') 
        {   
             $("#results_ajax").html("<div class='AppleRed'>Sorry There were Errors: " + data.error_message + "</div>");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#results_ajax").html("<div>"+ data.disp + "</div");
        }


    }, "json");

    return false;

});
```

});

When the user enters data into a form and submits the form gets submitted. I know that `data.error == 'TRUE'` gets hit because when I cause an error on purpose I get my error message.

I know that I am building up the results for `data.disp` as they are:

```
<div class='paragraph_style'><br />

<strong> San Jose College Park</strong>
<br/>2.33 miles<br />Out Of Stock
<strong> San Jose Westgate</strong>
<br/>3.35 miles<br />Out Of Stock

</div>
```

Using Firebug I see this come back, It looks good

But it does not get displayed.

I have been pulling my hair out for 3 hours!

UPDATE: Definitely a problem with my string, an encoding issue. I replaced my string with the work "Hello" and it works. Why did I not think of such a simple test sooner...

UPDATE 2: I am using this:

```
$m=array();
preg_match_all('/<p>[\s\S]*?<strong>([\s\S]*?)<\/p>/i',$buffer,$m);

foreach($m[1] as $mnum=>$match) 
{ 
    $displayString .="<br /><strong>";
    $displayString .= $match;
    $displayString .="<br />";
}
```

It is this line `$displayString .= $match;` Maybe I don't know how to output the value of `$m[1]`? What happens here is `$buffer` is curl output and I find all instances of

and they go into $m. Any advice?

EDIT: I tried wrapping the jquery `.html()` in a `try/catch` and nothing happens, I never hit it or get the alert.

```
try
{
    $("#results_ajax").html("<div>"+ data.disp + "</div>");
    alert($("#results_ajax").html());
}
catch(err)
{
    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
    txt+="Error description: " + err.description + "\n\n";
    txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
    alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: how are you encoding your JSON? If youre not using `json_encode` in PHP are you sure youre escaping everything correctly?

Comment: looks like missing a bracket on the end of your div.

   $("#results_ajax").html("<div>"+ data.disp + "</div");

Comment: @timh - I saw that, not the problem, it was myself trying to format it for the box

Comment: @prodigitalson - I took my json strong and did a `json_encode($mystring)` on it and still nothing. I am stumped. I have used this a few times and when it fails it works, just not when it actually builds up the right data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after your `$("#results_ajax").html("<div>"+ data.disp + "</div>");` call, do an `alert($("#results_ajax").html());` to see the html that actually got inserted.

It is possible it is the newlines you have embedded in the string.  Try generating the same string without the newlines to see if that is where the problem lies.

Comment: @Brandon - I did that and it never reaches. I narrowed it down to one section of code, specifically in the `for` loop where I try and add `$math` to my `displayString` See my update above

Comment: oh yeah somtimes you get an exception and "nothing happens".  Wrap the code where you set the .html() inside a try/catch block and see if you are getting an exception.  This can happen when assigning bad html

Comment: How do I add the $match above to my string to display? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It looks reasonable to me.  Just for grins, instead of **displayString .= $match** try **displayString .= $mnum . "</strong>"**.  That will send back html similar to what you want and we know for sure it will not have any newlines in it.  Also make sure you've declared your 'txt' variable you are using in your catch block.  And I am assuming you've used FireBug to put a breakpoint at the top of your function(data) { } callback and stepped through line by line to see where things go wrong?

Comment: @Brandon - Replacing `$match` with `$mnum` outputs the position in the array, in this case 0 - 9. Not I just need to figure out why I dont get data from `$match`

Comment: @Brandon - i have firebugI placed a breakpoint, but for some reason then I get a no javascript on this page and nothing is hit

Comment: So, if I understand you, everything worked when you used $mnum?  It seems very likely it is the newlines I assume are inside $match.  Try **displayString .= str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n"), '', $match);** and see if that makes it all work.

Comment: @Todd you should get rid of "json" and check what is in `data`.

Comment: @Todd - Also strange about the breakpoint not working.  What version of FF and Firebug are you using?  Some of the FF4 betas had a bug where you need to disable “Show XmlHttpRequests” option in the Firebug Console panel or else the ajax completion function would never fire.

Comment: @Brandon - Well what works is the `.html()` gets displayed using `$mnum` but that just displays array position, no the data in the position. I am using FF 4 and FireBug 1.7.

Comment: #Brandon - Yup it was the \n inside the `$match`! it works! Thank you so much. I will mention you in the footer on Hacker News.